# Async Function returning "undefined" once reaching SetInterval in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, return

For some reason my script will return once it reaches the "ticker" setinterval loop instead of doing whats inside of the loop and then returning.

Why is it returning early instead of doing the setinerval?

**The javascript code**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function test(url3) {
    let counter = 0;
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            defaultViewport: null
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const url = 'https://yandex.com/images/';

        await page.goto(url);

        await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelector('.input__cbir-button').firstElementChild.click();
        })

        await page.focus('input[name="cbir-url"]')
        await page.keyboard.type(url3)
        await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
        page
        .on('response', response =>{
            //console.log(`${response.url()}`)
          if(`${response.url()}` == "https://yandex.com/clck/jclck/"){
              counter++;
          }
        })
```

**SetInterval function where it messes up**

```
        var ticker = setInterval(async () => {
                if(counter === 2){
                    clearInterval(ticker)
                    if(page.$('.cbir-no-results__content' !== null)){ 
                        await browser.close();
                        return('no images found');
                    } else {
                        await page.screenshot({path: 'test.png', fullPage: true});
                        await browser.close();
                    }
                }
        })

    } catch(err) {
        //console.log(err)
    }

}
```

**Return**

```
test("animage.jpg").then(ans => {
    console.log(ans)
})
```

Comment: You may want to post the script, otherwise it's hard to figure out what's going on

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally posted before I was finished.

Comment: You can't return from the body of a setInterval call the way you're trying to do. Look up returning from a setInterval. Your code reaches the setInterval, queues up the asynchronous work in the background, then returns because there's nothing else for the function to execute. Also, why are you using a setInterval but not passing an interval to it?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will always return a number: the id of the timer that you can then pass to `clearInterval`. What you likely want is to wrap the *entire thing* in a Promise which it then resolved when your condition is met:

```
// no need for async, we're explicitly returning a Promise
function test() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const handle = setInterval(() => {
      if (conditionMet) {
        clearInterval(handle);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 100); // or however often
  });
}
```

This is one of the few times where it is correct to explicitly construct a Promise.